# How to write where condition on the basis of selected value

Tags: sql-server

I have a multi select drop down containing 20 values.
User can select all or few.

I want to write a query

1. if user has selected all the values then I don't want to pass all the selected values. (I will pass 0 to identify that all values are selected)
2. If use has selected few(or not all) then I want to pass only those selected values. (I will be passing comma separated values ex 101,102,103,104)

On the basis of the values I want write a join table or use it in a where condition

I have done something like as follows but it seem not working.

WHERE: Following throwing error (`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`)

```
DECLARE @EntitiyIds  AS varchar(2500) = '0'
SELECT * 
FROM Tb_CompanyType 
WHERE Id  IN (
            CASE WHEN @EntitiyIds <> '0' THEN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.Split(@EntitiyIds, ','))
                 WHEN @EntitiyIds =  '0' THEN (SELECT Id FROM Tb_CompanyType) END 
          )
```

INNER JOIN: (Following is not giving proper output)

```
DECLARE @EntitiyIds  AS VARCHAR(2500) = '101'

SELECT * FROM Tb_CompanyType CT
INNER JOIN Tb_Company TC ON 
                        CASE  WHEN @EntitiyIds = '0' AND TC.CompanyId = CT.Id THEN 1
                              WHEN @EntitiyIds <> '0' AND TC.CompanyId = (SELECT Item FROM dbo.Split(@EntitiyIds, ',')) THEN 1 END = 1
```

*dbo.Split returns table containing comma separated values*

Kindly help

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Tb_CompanyType
WHERE  @EntitiyIds = '0'
        OR Id IN (SELECT Item
                  FROM   dbo.Split(@EntitiyIds, ','))
```

Comment: This is the pattern that I use in a lot of reporting scenarios, compared to using a paired union statement I find it is superior in terms of readability (it is clear that we want the same output fields, in the two filter scenarios) and usability. (Don't have to declare select fields and other join conditions a second time)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps.

```
SELECT Id FROM Tb_CompanyType where @EntitiyIds =  '0'
UNION ALL
SELECT Item FROM dbo.Split(@EntitiyIds, ',') s where @EntitiyIds <>  '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message your provided, it seems that your sub-query is returning more than one rows. You last query segment's last line seems problematic:

```
DECLARE @EntitiyIds  AS VARCHAR(2500) = '101'

SELECT * FROM Tb_CompanyType CT
INNER JOIN Tb_Company TC ON 
                        CASE  WHEN @EntitiyIds = '0' AND TC.CompanyId = CT.Id THEN 1
                              WHEN @EntitiyIds <> '0' AND TC.CompanyId = (SELECT Item FROM dbo.Split(@EntitiyIds, ',')) THEN 1 END = 1
```

Change the last

```
SELECT Item FROM dbo.Split(@EntitiyIds, ',')
```

to

```
SELECT top 1 Item FROM dbo.Split(@EntitiyIds, ',')
```